# WebRTC: how to detect when a stream or track gets removed from a PeerConnection, in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, stream, webrtc, peer-connection

`onremovestream` has been deprecated (and removed from Firefox), while `onremovetrack` is not yet implemented in Firefox.

How do I detect when a stream or track is being removed in Firefox?

Comment: If the user leaves the room then the peerconnection closes and this will trigger oniceconnectionstatechange  and also onsignalingstatechange  events, both iceConnectionState and signalingState  will be 'closed'.

Comment: This is correct. However, I am getting a consistent delay between the user leaving the room and oniceconnectionstatechange actually being fired (sometimes).

Comment: @DanieleMolinari Please update your question with more specifics about the problem you're trying to solve. From your comment it sounds like you're trying to detect a remote peer dropping, which has nothing to do with negotiating away a track (which was what `onremovestream` was for).

Comment: @jib My question originally included an "how to detect when the user leaves the room" part. Since @Karthik is right on the `oniceconnectionstatechange`, I removed it from the question. What I am trying to solve is the case when a user adds multiple video streams, then removes one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use [`onremovetrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/onremovetrack) on the receiving *stream*:

```
pc.ontrack = ({track, streams: [stream]}) => {
  track.onunmute = () => {
    if (!video.srcObject) video.srcObject = stream;
  };
  stream.onremovetrack = ({track}) => {
    console.log(`${track.kind} track was removed.`);
    if (!stream.getTracks().length) {
      console.log(`stream ${stream.id} emptied (effectively removed).`);
    }
  };
};
```

The above `ontrack` will run when e.g. the other side adds a track (and negotiates):

```
const sender = pc.addTrack(track, stream);
```

Now, whenever that other side calls either `pc.removeTrack(sender)` or sets `transceiver.direction = "recvonly"` (and negotiates), you should see the `removetrack` event fire.

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/43enz7xu/show) that should work in all browsers.

#### Things to keep in mind

In standard WebRTC ("unified-plan") our `transceiver.receiver.track` isn't `ended` when this happens, because it is wired to the other side's `transceiver.sender`, not the other side's `transceiver.sender.track`.

Instead of ending, our receiving track is `muted` and removed from its stream(s).

This is because `pc.removeTrack(sender)` only sets the `sender.track` to `null` and `transceiver.direction` to `recvonly` (requiring negotiation).

A sender may thus resume sending data using `sender.replaceTrack(newTrack)` and setting `transceiver.direction = "sendrecv"` again. On this happening, our `receiver.track` would be `unmuted` again and reinserted into the stream(s), firing the `addtrack` events on the stream(s). This also fires the `track` event again. Explore all the events [in this blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/rtcrtptransceiver-explored/)'s interactive section.

A receiving track is only truly `ended` by `transceiver.stop()` (locally or through negotiation), or `pc.close()`.